# Excel MATCH formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to apply following command:

> =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$564880,0)),A2,"Z"&A2)

but, Excel said that is something wrong and marked A2,$D$2 part.
What is wrong?

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Works for me as posted. Typo somewhere?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use ; instead of , in your formula?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I tried to use ; instead od , - it marks me a whole D column with red lines, and after I hit enter answer me the same message. I don't know if it is important but I am using ; delimiter instead ,.

Comment: It works with: =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2;$D$2;$D$564879-0));A2;"Z"&A2). So, I should use ; instead of, and - instead of , in $D$564879-0 part.

Comment: So you tried: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2;$D$2:$D$564880;0));A2;"Z"&A2)`?

Comment: No, I tried: =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2;$D$2;$D$564879-0));A2;"Z"&A2). It looks nice. It pretty big file with over half a million rows with file and directory names.

Comment: `-0` isn't the same as `,0` which is looking for an exact match. I'm baffled that it works at all actually. Perhaps Rory can enlighten.

Comment: It seems you are right, because now ALL my cells has Z prefix in the C column. I didn't except that. I will check data more.

Comment: Correct formula is =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2;$D$2:$D$564879;0));A2;"Z"&A2) but my file is very big so 8 cpus still working.

Comment: I would like to mark Rory's answer as a solution, but I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: The @Rory have to post it as and answer, then you can accept it by clicking on the tick beside it.

Answer (score 0):

By popular demand ;)

Your formula should be:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2;$D$2:$D$564880;0));A2;"Z"&A2)`